# http_response_code() not functioning properly

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

Goal: change the `http_response_code` in php from `404` to `200`

I am currently using

```
<?php
http_response_code(200);
?>
```

but `httpstatus.io` is still pulling 404.

Clownery.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that would suggest you're pointing httpstatus.io at the wrong page. if its 404, that means your PHP code is not at the URL you're looking at, therefore the http_response_code() method will not be working. check your page address is accurate.

Comment: Thank you, I was forwarding 404 in my `.htaccess` to a php file, and then was requesting the 404 url that doesn't exist on `httpstatus.io`. Whats odd is that instead of using `http_response_code(200)` I used `header("Status: 200 OK");` and it functions how I was originally hoping.

Comment: OK - tip for the future, give that sort of detail in your original question, as it would be hard to understand what is causing the issue otherwise, and people won't be able to help. Glad you got it sorted :)